# ACS/AKS cluster with linux and windows node

Tags: kubernetes, acs, linux-containers, windows-container, azure-aks

Does Azure container service or Azure Kubernetes service support a cluster with linux and windows worker nodes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, though it is scheduled for a future release. You can use [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine) to create a mixed node cluster, but I think that is still beta/preview as well.